# Code listing with Title above it?

Tags: listings, tcolorbox, minted

I recently checked one of my Professor's tests and saw that his questions involved some code blocks that that have title for it, with a box surrounding it and horizontal lines that do not extend to the line numbers, as below:
[image]
How can this be done in LaTeX?

Comment: Try to play with `tcolorbox` by looking at `minted` in the doc of `tcolorbox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, where options in package `listings` is only partially used, and package `Tikz` provides much more than just some fill-colors:

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
 \noindent\tikz{
    \node[draw,minimum width=3cm,
          fill=teal!10] (N) at (0,0) {robot.h}; 
    \draw (N.west) -- +(-4.55,0);
    \draw (N.east) -- +(4.55,0);
 }

 \begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left]
class Robot
public:
 robot();
void function();
int countHumans();
    
 \end{lstlisting}  
 
 \hrule
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is wonderful. Thank you for the help!